# Doctrine2 cascade remove with multiple parents

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, cascade

I have a series of classes with a slightly complicated set of references between the properties of those classes. I am trying to remove an entity and have that remove be cascaded to its children, but I'm running into foreign key constraint errors. Here is an example of my class structure:

```
<?php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="student_tests")
 */
class StudentTest implements IEntityAccess {

/**
 *
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @var StudentTestItem[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="StudentTestItem", mappedBy="studentTest", cascade{"remove","persist"})
 */
protected $studentTestItems;

/**
 * @var Test
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Test", inversedBy="studentTests")
 */
protected $test;
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $created;
/**
 * @var User
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="studentTests")
 */
protected $student;
}


//...
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="student_test_items")
 */
class StudentTestItem {

/**
 *
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @var StudentTest
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="StudentTest", inversedBy="studentTestItems")
 */
protected $studentTest;
/**
 * @var User
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="studentTestItems", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $student;

/**
 * @var TestItem
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TestItem", inversedBy="studentTestItems", cascade{"persist"})
 */
protected $testItem;
}


//...
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="tests")
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Test implements IEntityAccess {
/**
 *
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $startDate;
/**
 * @var StudentTest[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="StudentTest", mappedBy="test" )
 */
protected $studentTests;

/**
 * @var TestItem[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TestItem", mappedBy="test", cascade={"all"})
 */
protected $items;
}



//...
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="test_items")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
abstract class TestItem {
/**
 *
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @var Test
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Test", inversedBy="items")
 */
/**
 * @var StudentTestItem[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="StudentTestItem", mappedBy="testItem")
 */
protected $studentTestItems;

}



/**
 * This is the primary user object. Used for login and all the other
 * good stuff.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable, IEntityAccess
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @var int
 */
private $id;
/**
 * @var StudentTest[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="StudentTest", mappedBy="student", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $studentTests;
/**
 * @var StudentTestItem[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="StudentTestItem", mappedBy="student", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $studentTestItems;
}
```

Let's say I want to delete a student test, and have that delete cascaded to its StudentTestItem children. To do so, I run the following code inside of a controller.

```
//... blah blah class definition
/**
* Delete a student test
*
* @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
* @Route("/studenttest/delete", name="student_test_delete")
*/
public function DeleteStudentTestAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $studentTest = $em->getRepository("MyAcmeBundle:StudentTest")->findOneBy(array("id" => 3));

    $em->remove($studentTest);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('student_delete_success'));
}
```

When I try to run that code, I get the following error message:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM student_tests WHERE id = ?' with params [3]:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`my_acme_bundle/student_test_items`, CONSTRAINT `FK_71FA2A7F36BB1A1` FOREIGN KEY (`student_test_id`) REFERENCES `student_tests` (`id`))
500 Internal Server Error - DBALException
```

NOW, if I remove all references to studentTestItems from the classes, i.e. I comment out $studentTestItems from the TestItem and User classes, it deletes fine without that issue. Why is this happening? Does Doctrine keep track of the parent references through associations or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to add `ON DELETE CASCADE` to the foreign key constraint. Try changing the following association in `class StudentTestItem`:

```
/**
 * @var StudentTest
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="StudentTest", inversedBy="studentTestItems")
 */
protected $studentTest;
```

To this:

```
/**
 * @var StudentTest
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="StudentTest", inversedBy="studentTestItems")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="student_test_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
protected $studentTest;
```

Comment: Thanks, we realized this was the issue. Seems strange that it's necessary though given the cascade={"remove"} -- in my opinion Doctrine really needs to step up their documentation game.

Comment: I know how you feel. I get more frustrated with Symfony's documentation of its various component configurations and the fact that it reads like a "text book" rather than a reference document. The latter is better suited for development.